# What is "prescriptive infirmity"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Woman’s prescriptive infirmity had stalked into the sunlight, which had clothed it in the freshness of an originality.

What does woman's prescriptive infirmity mean in the above passage from Thomas Hardy's Far from the madding crowd Chapter 1.?

Comment: We're going to need more context.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed; I don't see that it could easily have been 'answered by using commonly-available references'. I had to think quite hard to work out the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Bathsheba, riding on top of a cartload of furniture, unpacks a bedroom mirror and looks at herself, apparently just from vanity.

Oxford Languages defines *prescriptive* as (2) *(of a right, title, or institution) having become legally established or accepted by long usage or the passage of time.*

Hardy seems to be saying that vanity is traditionally regarded as being a feminine weakness, and Bathsheba is displaying it in public rather than in the privacy of her bedroom.